# Use curl with a file of commands

Tags: bash, curl

I am using curl from a BASH shell.  I would like to create a text file of commands to send via curl and then somehow have all of them run at once.  It's been a long time since I dealt with UNIX commands, but can someone show me how to accomplish this please (assuming I have a file created called commands.txt)?

Editing this post to include an example of the file of commands I would like to execute in batch...

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/1' -d '{"firstName":"Domino","lastName":"Derval"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/2' -d '{"firstName":"Elektra","lastName":"King"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/3' -d '{"firstName":"Fiona","lastName":"Volpe"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/4' -d '{"firstName":"Holly","lastName":"Goodhead"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/5' -d '{"firstName":"Honey","lastName":"Rider"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/6' -d '{"firstName":"Jill","lastName":"Masterton"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/7' -d '{"firstName":"Kissy","lastName":"Suzuki"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/8' -d '{"firstName":"Mary","lastName":"Goodnight"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/9' -d '{"firstName":"Miranda","lastName":"Frost"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/10' -d '{"firstName":"Molly","lastName":"Warmflash"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/11' -d '{"firstName":"Paula","lastName":"Caplan"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/12' -d '{"firstName":"Penelope","lastName":"Smallbone"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/13' -d '{"firstName":"Pussy","lastName":"Galore"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/14' -d '{"firstName":"Strawberry","lastName":"Fields"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/15' -d '{"firstName":"Sylvia","lastName":"Trench"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/16' -d '{"firstName":"Tatiana","lastName":"Romanova"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/17' -d '{"firstName":"Tilly","lastName":"Masterton"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/18' -d '{"firstName":"Vesper","lastName":"Lynd"}'
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/foo/property/19' -d '{"firstName":"Xenia","lastName":"Onatopp"}'
```

Comment: text commands to be sent via curl? sent where? providing a web-facing script that blindly executes any shell commands sent to it by a remote user is highly highly highly risky.

Comment: I am running some tests on my local machine.  I have elastic search set up and I want to send a bunch of commands to it in batch for development purposes.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a short example of the contents of your file and how precisely you wish to use them with `curl`.

Comment: do you really mean 'and then somehow have all of them run at once.'? Or do you mean, 'sit back and let curl process each command in order, automatically'? Good luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### create a script `download.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash    
# put all your commands here
curl ...
.
.
.
curl ...
```

#### make `download.sh` executable

```
$ chmod +x download.sh
```

#### run `donwload.sh`

```
$ ./download.sh
```